# PowerShell "cat <file>" with blank lines treats blanks as spaces

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I've seen a lot of posts asking how to remove blank lines from files in powershell, but I'm trying to keep them, without resorting to bodyashtml in the send-mailmessage call.

I have a file, mail.txt, which is:

```
mail file blah blah blah

hshshshshs
```

When you cat that file, it looks ok; the main problem is, when you treat the "cat " as a variable, like

```
$BLAH = $(cat ${MAIL_FILE})
echo "blah is $BLAH"
```

it returns as

```
blah is mail file blah blah blah  hshshshshs
```

So when it's passed as part of the body to send-mailmessage:

```
$BODY = @"

this is line two

$(cat ${MAIL_FILE})
"@

send-mailmessage `
  -from ${FROM} `
  -to ${MAIL_RECIPIENT} `
  -subject ${SUBJECT} `
  -body ${BODY} `
  -smtpserver ${RELAYHOST} `
  -priority ${PRIORITY}
```

It comes out in the email as

```
line two

mail file blah blah blah  hshshshshs
```

instead of

```
<blank line here>
line two

mail file blah blah blah

hshshshshshhs
```

So how do I go about "maintaining" the file as-is, passed to the body of the message and not as an attachment? And ideally, how to get a leading blank line in that body too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Content` (alias `cat`) actually reads the content as an array of strings, each representing a line. In powershell 3.0 you can use the `-Raw` flag to get the entire file.

```
$BLAH = cat ${MAIL_FILE} -Raw
```

Otherwise you might use the `join` operator:

```
$BLAH = (cat ${MAIL_FILE}) -join "`r`n"
```

Comment: The -join worked, thanks! I should have mentioned i'm using 2.0